# Ubuntu 14.04 is there a way to directly trace an application in real time?

Tags: 14.04, updates, firefox, crash, gthumb

On Ubuntu 14.04 is there a way to directly trace an application in real time?
This maybe on here but I could not find a page in search with "Google" or "site search" that I could say applied. I did find info on tracing Ubuntu crashes, as in the operating system, not usable on a Application crash as far as I can tell. (I may be wrong?)

I'm having a problem mainly with Firefox(Occasional(One or none for hours.) to almost continuous(Every blipping few minutes.).) but it very very occasionally affects Gthumb, what happens is the App(s) crashes(Completely ends, Firefox opens restart window with info that is simply worthless. Addins and Firefox version. No blippin help there.).  Never has there been any problem with the crash affecting Ubuntu its self(Stays working perfectly.).  As far as I can tell every other application I have loaded works same as always.  Just Firefox to a major extent, and Gthumb to a very minor extent.  By the way Chrome, Ubuntu software center, Synaptic, Gdebi, Terminal, Update, all work accessing the web normally(Ubuntu software takes forever to get application images but this is "normal" as far as I have read.)

I have tried Firefox with and without addins in safe mode, no change.  I have tried three different versions of Firefox and even a portable version, no change.  I have used Synaptics package manager's fix broken packages, no change. I have updated several times no change.

As for crash logs I did a lot of looking searching and found no info on crash logs the closest I got was about var and logs but I don't have files listed, not sure if they were for my version of Linux, and looking around I can't find any in /var/logs or /var/crash which were the places I figured to find a crash log.

What I think caused the problem was an update on Dec 23rd.  Since I don't update constantly I'm not sure when the update item came out that caused the problem.(See bellow.)

Anyway I figure the only way to figure out what is going on is to trace the crash as it happens in some way.  Of course someone mite have an idea from the updates as to what would affect Firefox mostly?

In the three screen shots bellow you can see the updates.
[image: Screenshot_from_2018-02-02_20_10_00] [image: Screenshot_from_2018-02-02_20_10_40] [image: Screenshot_from_2018-02-02_20_11_21]

In answer to question is this a duplicate of "How do I know which file a program is trying to access?", Its not because the problem in that link is some package is missing and they need to find it and install or update the package, while my problem is a package(?) Firefox(and Gthumb) accesses crashes the program(s) randomly.  So they are not the same problem but the info in that Post maybe useful in tracking things down.

I'm still looking for the answer and will update when I find one.  I'm going threw a big mess from `lsof -c firefox`.  So far I found Firefox does have logs, they are in a hidden directory under your home directory, there are a bunch of different ones, so far I have three file types I need to find readers for as they are not just text `.dmp .extra .mozlz4`.

Comment: You can attach strace or gdb to the firefox process to see what it's doing, but unless you know your way around the codebase, it will be overwhelming.

Comment: I maybe saying what I need to do wrong maybe trace is too advanced, I want to see what libs, packages, etc. Firefox(Gthumb's crashes are so seldom I'm not real worried about it.) calls or uses when it crashes, so I can find what is now causing Firefox to crash.

Comment: `lsof` should list libraries opened by a process

Comment: Thanks Muru I found "lsof -c firefox" on that page you linked.  I got a list of things Firefox links, I'll look threw them and see if I can figure what is broken, synaptic is usually helpful with broken packages.  Thanks.  I also have found some GUI's to access the other programs "strace or gdb" you mentioned so maybe I can figure this out.  If not maybe I will get closer and can ask a better question.

Comment: One other thing for anyone looking while I found info that mite help me in my problem on Murus linked page it is not exactly the same problem.  The problem there is some package is missing and they need to find it and install or update the package, while my problem is a package Firefox accesses crashes the program randomly.  So they are different but maybe require similar solutions.  My problem in finding help seems to be my not knowing what to search for.

Comment: I think in the end maybe I will need to rewrite the title and then put in info on what I find and what tools, etc. I needed to know about to hunt down the problem.  Maybe edit out the extra stuff in the post.  The older post doesn't list the GUI's for the terminal programs mentioned(Which mite make them more user friendly.), I haven't even loaded them yet, so can't tell what works and is easy for a less experienced Linux user like me.

Comment: Still working on this, its kinda a drag, since the thing isn't in crash mode all the time.  So its do something, run for a while think maybe I got it, then it crashes a half dozen times in a row.  At least its not like windows and I can just restart the program without all the hassle of a reboot.  Learning a few things.  Found a Samba error still looking into it, I don't use file sharing right now.  I'm not sure why its installed and running by default in home version of Ubuntu?  It even has a guest account setup?  I'll have to fix it, already turned it off, guest will be gone or changed.